# Slow MySQL distinct with where

Tags: mysql

I have a large table that has two columns (among others):

- event_date
- country

This query is very fast:

```
select distinct event-date from my_table
```

This query is also very fast:

```
select * from my_table where country = 'US'
```

However, this query is very slow:

```
select distinct event_date from my_table where country = 'US'
```

I tried adding all combinations of indexes, including one on both columns. Nothing makes the third query faster.

Any insights?

Comment: can you show as the explain plan for your last query?

Comment: Can you add the output of `explain select distinct event_date from my_table where country = 'US'`?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE my_table ADD INDEX my_idx (event_date, country);`

Comment: @Alex if at all, (country, event_date) is the correct order. Order matters with multi-column indexes!

Comment: @Alex That did it! I had the index on the columns the other way around and it was still slow. Please post the answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD INDEX my_idx (event_date, country);
```

Comment: A follow up question: If I needed to reference more than one column in the where clause, do I need a two column index for each one or a single index with more than two columns? Thanks.

Comment: It all depends on your query, your table size and some other parameters. Just keep in mind, more indexes you have slower your `INSERT, UPDATE` operations will be. If you don't have that many `INSERT, UPDATE`s every second, minute, etc you can add more and more different indexes and optimize them for every query you have. But in real projects, usually there just few indexes that you should really have.

Comment: I understand all of that. My follow up question was, if I had another column in the where clause, do I add an index for (event_date, country, other_column) or two indexes (event_date, country) and (event_date, other_column). I can try both and see which is faster.

Comment: Yes you can, but usually there is no need for that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried staging the results in a temporary table, adding an index, then completing the query from there? Not sure if this will work in MySQL, but it's a trick I use successfully in MSSQL quite often.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS staging AS (
    SELECT event_date FROM my_table WHERE country = 'US'
);
CREATE INDEX ix_date ON staging(event_date);
SELECT DISTINCT event_date FROM staging;
```

Comment: Are you saying that these three queries will run every time I need this data? And that the three queries combines will take less time than my query?

Comment: It _can_ do, but it depends heavily on your data. I use this technique more often than I use indexes, generally because selecting a small subset and then indexing that tends to be much quicker than a single select statement, especially when breaking out correlated subqueries, or multiple clauses that don't play well during indexing. As I said though YMMV